# excel custom function

Tags: excel, function

[image: excel table]

I have this table that contain more than 6K rows.
I need a function, that will run on each "A" Column's cell 
and check -> if cell on "b" is bold than copy it,
if not, copy the cell above it.

I fount this function on the internet, but im not using VB and it will be easier if someone that already know how to use VB functions in excel than learn it from the beginning.

this code replaces the G column cells with numbers, as you can see.

```
Sub BoldCells()
Dim TheRange As Range
Dim TheCell As Range
Set TheRange = Range("G1", Range("G65536").End(xlUp))
For Each TheCell In TheRange
If TheCell.Font.Bold = True Then
TheCell = 7
Else: TheCell = 0
End If
Next TheCell
End Sub
```

Help will be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you, for example, want both A7 and A8 have value "Mobile Phones"?

Comment: For example from the table above: if B1 == text bold than A1 = B1. if B2 == text bold than A2 = A1;

Comment: Hi Mitz, what version of Excel are you using? Also, do you only need to do this one time or repeatedly?

Comment: Hi PowerUser, the Excel version is 14.0.6123. I need this only 1 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how efficient this is, but looks like working with 10 lines or so of data.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, str As String
    Set rng = Range("b1")
    str = ""
    Do
        If rng.Font.Bold Then
            str = rng.Value
        End If
        rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = str
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until IsEmpty(rng)
End Sub
```